# how to read all file contents in a directory with Laravel

Tags: laravel, filesystems

I have so many files in a directory and I want to read all of them and save them in Database.
I know how to do it but the way i know is that all file contents will load to the memory at the same time and web application will be dead. I tend to put some limits like it reads 300 files at the same time and after that it goes through the next 300 files.
as you can see I have 736 files here.

[image]

this is my sample file contents :
[image]

I'm using this code to split them.

```
    foreach ($contents as $content) {
        $slice = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $content);
    }
```

and results : [image]

Comment: If you need to separate the contents of the files for different columns, please update your question. Can easily be solved with regex.

Comment: And what columns should slice[0]....slice[4] go in what table name?

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can see what I am trying to get at.

Comment: Slice[0] in metadata, Slice[1] in data1, Slice[2] in data2 and Slice[3] in data3

Comment: Ok see my solution below, and you have not provided table name yet

Comment: Is that what you needed?

Comment: my table name is informations and one thing i forgot is that i need to move those files to another folder which saved in database, is this correct ? Storage::disk('public')->move($file , 'done/'.Str::of($file)->after('/'));

Comment: Looks like it should work ok! I will update my answer again.

Comment: Thank you! can you explain this line ?     if (count($contents) === 10)

Comment: It is just for chunking, whatever you set it to, that is the number of files you will insert in one go.

Comment: Also, I have added toMove, since you dont want to move your files until the DB operation is successful.

Comment: You saved my day!!!! thank you so much !

Comment: Glad to help :) Upvote too if you don't mind

Comment: Done :) thanks again.

Comment: my reputation is less than 15 , so it doesn't change votes for public,

Comment: All good! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel's [filesytem](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem) and the Storage facade to achieve this:

```
$files = Storage::disk('public')->files('path/to/files');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $contents = Storage::disk('public')->get($file);
    // Save contents to DB;
}
```

You could also do them in batches by building up an array of contents

```
$files = Storage::disk('public')->files('path/to/files');
$contents = [];
$toMove = [];

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $content = Storage::disk('public')->get($file);
    $slice = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $content);
    
    $contents[] = [
         'metadata' => $slice[0],
         'data1' => $slice[1],
         'data2' => $slice[2],
         'data3' => $slice[3],
    ];
    
    $toMove[] = $file;

    if (count($contents) === 10) {
        DB::table('informations')->insert($contents);

        foreach($toMove as $file) {
            Storage::disk('public')
                ->move($file , 'done/'.Str::of($file)->after('/')); 
        }

        $contents = [];
        $toMove = [];
    }
}

if (count($contents)) {
    DB::table('informations')->insert($contents);

    foreach($toMove as $file) {
        Storage::disk('public')
            ->move($file , 'done/'.Str::of($file)->after('/')); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using laravel filesystem, every file has 3 line and i need to separate them and save them into 3 different fields in DB. I can separate them like this :
array:4 [
  0 => "Metadata"
  1 => "test"
  2 => "test"
  3 => "test"
]

with this code :         
foreach ($contents as $content) {
            $slice = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $content);
}
it's not working, i can't save them, and also i think your code is still the same, it loads all files at the same time, isn't it ?

Comment: Please post sample file contents. And the columns they should be put into db as.

Comment: Please update your question with the file contents, and the output of $slice = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $content

Comment: Updated question, please check it